# add_column for references (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema

I have the following Rails migration which works perfectly (irrelevant pieces removed):

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.text :body
  t.references :post
end
```

Now I'd like to add an `author` column to my `comments` table (which is the userid of a user), but I have no idea how to do it (I'm tempted to just write the MySql-specific syntax using an `execute`).

I've been looking at add_column [here](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#M001658) which doesn't mention `references`. I've actually found [TableDefinition#references](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M001737) but I have no idea how to use it with an `add_column` statement.

Is this possible? Also, is it true that, for MySql, the "references" functionality does not actually establish relationships between the tables?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

While it's too late to get any points out of this, I thought I'd post the best way for posterity :)

use `change_table` instead of `create_table` to add columns to a table that already exists, with all the TableDefinition goodness:

```
self.up do
  change_table :comments do |t|
    t.references :author
  end
end
```

This might seem trivial, but other gems like Devise make heavy use of their own custom table definitions, and this way you can still use them.

Comment: Okay, so I add an author field to the comments table and I use references. Does that make a difference in MySql? Do I still need to change the model?

Comment: Yes, you'd still need to add "has_many :comments" in your author.rb, and "belongs_to :author" in your comment.rb.  The migration code only creates fields in the database, which are useless until you call the right ActiveRecord methods I've listed here.

Comment: Is this still the best way in rails3? Also, this should really be marked the answer...

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way.  In fact, I just used it in a rails 3 app this weekend (during Rails Rumble). And I'm almost 2 years late to be marked the right answer - this is an old question!

Comment: @Jaime Bellmyer if you use @yar in your comment and you say why this answer beats the best answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @yar - this is the best answer because the user was asking how to get table definitions like `t.references`, which you can't do with add_column.  The Devise gem implements its own custom table definitions, so you don't have to fill your migrations with dozens of tough-to-remember field names.  Hopefully, this practice will become more popular with gems and plugins in rails.

Comment: @Jaime Bellmyer, okay +1 and best answer and I've also learned something. I'll have to check out the Devise gem, too, I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @Jamie Bellmyer What would be the best way to do the reverse migration? I like to keep my migrations clean both ways.

Comment: @Jackson Miller there isn't a t.unreference to undo your reference addition, but you can use the long way with t.remove :author_id in the example above.  If you used "t.references :author, :polymorphic => true" then you'll also need to have "t.remove author_type" in your down migration.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is 4-5 years old. Even though this can work, this is no longer the acceptable method for Rails 4+. Please see the DRY, one-liner suggestion by Rajeev Kannav Sharma & Josh Crozier

Answer (score 102):

```
add_reference :table_name, :reference, index: true
```

Comment: This is the good answer, at less for _Rails 4_. Here the [API reference](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference)

Comment: Agreed. This should now be the 'new' correct answer for Rails 4+.

Comment: You also can pass `add_reference :table_name, :reference, polymorphic: true, index: true`

Comment: For my business, I did it as `add_reference :users, :tenant, foreign_key: true`.

Answer (score 38):

Finally got it

```
add_column :locations, :state_id , :integer, :references => "states"
```

Comment: Chickoklkar, that's great. If you could please delete your other answer, and also if you could link to the Rails docs, that would great. Thanks!

Comment: Does this actually do anything special? I can't find any documentation that says that add_column will actually do anything with the :references symbol in options.

Comment: This was probably correct answer in 2012, but with Rails 4 it isthe answer by @rajeev-kannav-sharma.

Answer (score 22):

First, do:

```
script/generate migration AddAuthorIdToComments
```

Open the generated file and add this line:

```
add_column :comments, :author_id, :integer
```

Then in your model files:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => "author_id"
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => User
end
```

Comment: very nice, thanks for that. Of course adding the column as an integer is not what I was hoping for, but since that's what the original migration does anyway... THANKS for outlining how to setup the relationships in the model classes.

Comment: Simple truth is, you just can't use references in this scenario, because is only available for table definitions. And yes, as Craig says, migrations don't care about setting foreign keys in database.

Comment: Okay, I get it re: table definitions: at the column level it's not available (only at the table level). A question: if the column in User is called "id", it works, right? "author_id" is the name of the new column in comments ONLY, right?

Comment: Yes, the connection between those two is defined on the model level (see foreign_key, class_name).

Comment: What does the "class_name => User" do?

Comment: Only for the protocol. The classname must every time in "". So the right syntax is   belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User" and not belongs_to :author, :class_name => User

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've looked at this, but last I checked migrations don't support creating foreign keys. Fortunately, however, [there is a plug-in for it](http://github.com/harukizaemon/foreign_key_migrations/tree/master). I've used this and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the column by `add_column(:table, :column_name, :type, :options)` in a new Migration.

Comment: Thanks Mike. What would the :type and :options be?