# How do I relate two fields with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-key-relationship

Just starting to use Ruby on Rails to see what its like.

I have a user model with an id and a post model with an adderId. The adderId of the post model should be the user id of the user that created it.

How can I relate these with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rails convention for foreign keys would give your Post model a user_id column rather than adderId.  You can break the convention, but that requires slightly more configuration, as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :adderId
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :adder, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :adderId
end
```

If you gave Post a user_id instead, you could do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'd recommend taking a look at the [Rails Guide for Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which covers all of the above and plenty more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493777/addcolumn-for-references-rails) seems to be doing what you're trying to do.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, I too am new to Ruby on Rails.