# Rails 3.1 add columns with change_table migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have one table called `profiles` with some columns.

Now I wish to add a few columns to this table using the `change`-method in rails 3.1. I created a migration with the following code:

```
def change
  change_table :profiles do |t|
    t.string :photo
    t.string :name
    t.references :user
  end
end
```

The migration works perfectly, but when I want to rollback I get

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: photo: ALTER TABLE "profiles" ADD "photo" varchar(255)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6):

The auto-generated migrations for adding columns in Rails 3.1 is in the format:

```
class AddColumnToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :table, :column, :type
  end
end
```

Perhaps try that syntax?

Comment: What about adding a reference with add_column? I guess I could do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493777/add-column-for-references-rails/493802#493802 But it would be more flexible to be able to add it directly in the migration somehow.

Comment: @martnu: Adding a reference just adds an ID field of type integer to the table - you could replicate it with `add_column :profiles, :user_id, :integer`.

Comment: `reference` also adds an index on the `assoc_id` column, which is useful.

Comment: According to the source, no such index is automatically added.  You can certainly add one manually, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to tell the migration how to revert itself:

```
def change
  change_table :profiles do |t|
    t.string :photo
    t.string :name
    t.references :user
  end

  reversible do |dir|
    dir.down do
      remove_column :profiles, :photo
      remove_column :profiles, :name
      remove_column :profiles, :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-reversible for more information.

Alternatively you could try using the old up and down methods which are still available like so:

```
def up
  change_table :profiles do |t|
    t.string :photo
    t.string :name
    t.references :user
  end
end

def down
  remove_column :profiles, :photo
  remove_column :profiles, :name
  remove_column :profiles, :user_id
end
```

More on up/down here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods