# Rails: How to migrate a database where I added a :belongs_to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rails-migrations

This is my first rails app, one I'm creating for the sole purpose of learning rails.

I created an app where I have Users and Products (and sessions, but this is not relevant here). After doing a rake db:mograte creating a few items and testing, I then wanted to add a relationship, where products belongs_to :users and a users has_many :products.

But of course, since I have already created the tables, there isn't any column there to save this information.

How do I make a migration on the database so it will reflect this model? Is there a console tool for it? Do I have to install a third party gem?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493777/add-column-for-references-rails

Comment: I concur. The above question is not a duplicate, but contains the answer that you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generally add columns right from the command line. Here is an example that might be relevant to your situation:

In the terminal, navigate to your Rails app and type:

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_products user_id:integer
```

This will create a migration automatically that has the user_id column in the products table. You can then migrate the database again to add the latest changes:

```
rake db:migrate
```

You should then have the minimum required for your has_many/belongs_to relationship.